# Destroy a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, destroy

I want to destroy a variable in ruby as if it had never existed. Here is an example:

```
> defined? a
=> "nil"
> a = 1
> defined? a
=> "local-variable"
```

Now I need to set variable a to "nil" when I do `defined?`.

I tried some things like:

```
> a = nil #Not working
=> nil
> defined? a 
=>  "local-variable"
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Nothing of that worked for me. Restarting the IRB will be okey, but I need to use outside IRB

Comment: Read the accepted answer to that question. The answer is: you cannot do that with local variables.

Comment: It didn't work because you have a local variable, and currently there is no way to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now (MRI 2.2 and before), there's no way to do this.